# avr_bridge example code not working with current git version?

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
it seems the example code for avr_bridge does not compile with the current version in the git repo. If I clone the git repository and use the example in the "test" directory (or the downloadable example), I get generated node_handle files which have a spin() without an additional char argument, while the example code contains a spin(char). Also, I get a compile error due to Msg not being defined, because it is missing a preceding "ros::" in main.cpp. Am I doing something wrong? If not, how do I get a working example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9676/avr_bridge-example-code-not-working-with-current-git-version?/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2011-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sadly, it doesn't compile. When you solve all the minor problems and it finally compiles, it doesn't work. Please take a look at this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/624/problems-using-avr_bridge-arduino-ros?answer=1092#1092 and download the latest code. You can then take imu_9drazor as an example of how to use it. I'll try to come back later, edit this post and provide a HelloWorld example I did yesterday (it uses a callback method, which imu_9drazor doesn't).

---

Ok, as promised, a simple `HelloWorld` example follows. Begin with reading the [avr_bridge Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/avr_bridge), if you haven't yet done so. I'm also assuming you all dear readers already understand what Arduino is (as I'm using an Arduino Duemilanove here) and have [Eclipse configured](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse) to work with it.

Take `callResponse.yaml` from the `HelloWorld` example provided in the old example project [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/avr_bridge/Tutorials/Hello%20World), for completness, these are it's contents:

```
port: /dev/ttyUSB0
name: callResponse
publish: #list of published topics
 response: #topic name
  type: std_msgs/String  #msg type
subscribe:
 call:
  type: std_msgs/String
```

Then run

```
rosrun avr_bridge gen_avr.py callResponse.yaml .
```

in the project's folder where you wish to use `avr_bridge` (generally do as it says in the [avr_bridge HelloWorld Wiki tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/avr_bridge/Tutorials/Hello%20World). I used the following `main.cpp` (a slight modification of the one provided in the aforementioned tutorial):

```
#include "WProgram.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <String.h>
#include "avr_ros/Ros.h"
#include "avr_ros/ros_string.h"

Publisher resp;

std_msgs::String call_msg;
std_msgs::String response_msg;

extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual()
{
  cli();
  for (;;);
}

void toggle()
{
    if (digitalRead(13) == LOW ) {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // set the LED on
    } else {
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // set the LED off
    }
}

void responseCallback(Msg* msg) {
    toggle();

    response_msg.data.setString(call_msg.data.getRawString());
    ros.publish(resp, &response_msg);
}

unsigned long pubTimer=0;
void setup(){
    //Set up the serial communicaton and wait a bit to make sure
    //that the program and grab its id before we go into any other
    //set up routines
    Serial.begin(57600);
    for (int i; i<100; i++) {ros.spin();delay(10);}

    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    resp = ros.advertise("response");
    ros.subscribe("call", responseCallback, &call_msg);

    call_msg.data.setMaxLength(30);
    response_msg.data.setMaxLength(60);

    pubTimer = millis();
}

void loop(){
    ros.spin();

    //Do other work
    delay(10);
}

int main(void)
{
    init();
    setup();

    for (;;) { loop(); }

    return 0;
}
```

and added those to `Ros.cpp`:

```
int ros_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    Serial.write(c);
    return 0;
}

int ros_getchar(FILE *stream)
{
    return Serial.read();
}
```

That's not yet the neatest use of `avr_bridge`, which I'm aware of (like I'm using a global variable in `callbackResponse`), but it worked for me, which I hope it will for you as well. Consult [avr_bridge HelloWorld Wiki tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/avr_bridge/Tutorials/Hello%20World) as to how to run it then (paragraph 5 for the time of this writing).

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-04-14**:
Thanks again Tom, it's working now. We had some problems with running out of RAM without noticing it though before, as the example allocates 300 bytes for the buffer. After cutting that down to the 128 it works now.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-04-08**:
Actually there is a imu.yaml file in the imu_9drazor/config directory and an example.yaml in avr_bridge/config.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-04-08**:
Thanks Tom, that helps :) What I'm still wondering about though is the missing "call_response.yaml" file that I'd have expected to be in the "imu_9drazor/src/imu_AVRdriver" directory. It'd be awesome if you could upload a example with callback and everything.